# Boost:: Dijkstra Shortest Path, how to get vertice index from path iterator?

Tags: c++, boost, dijkstra, boost-graph

Before you start reading, to help you understand my issue, I am telling that I have copied the code from this link: [Dijkstra Shortest Path with VertexList = ListS in boost graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156880/dijkstra-shortest-path-with-vertexlist-lists-in-boost-graph)

So.. I am rewriting my program code to use boost, but now when 99% is ready I am stuck with my GPS (for a game).
I have a list of nodes, which I added in a way which fortunately was easy to convert to the boost method. The thing I needed to do was just create a vertice variable like this:

```
Vertex Vx[MAX_NODES];
```

I copied the typedefs from the link I have given.

The way I add vertices is this:

```
            stringstream s;
            s << i;
            Vx[i] = add_vertex(s.str(),dgraph);
```

Where "i" equals an integer number. (eg int i = 9)

And eges are also easy to add. Now, I have my own structured array called "xNode". and eg :
xNode[i] holds all the information for X Y Z positions (xNode[i].X xNode[i].Y etc) of the nodes.

Now when using the code snippet from the link I have done this:

```
// Write shortest path 
std::cout << "Shortest path from " << startid << " to " << endid << ":" << std::endl; 
float totalDistance = 0; 
for(PathType::reverse_iterator pathIterator = path.rbegin(); pathIterator !=       path.rend(); ++pathIterator) 
{ 
    std::cout << source(*pathIterator, dgraph) << " -> " <<     target(*pathIterator, dgraph)
    << " = " << get( boost::edge_weight, dgraph, *pathIterator ) <<     std::endl; 
}
```

And this is where I am stuck, as "source(*pathIterator, dgraph)" and "target(*pathIterator, dgraph)
" Get addresses, but I need the vertice indexes to access xNode[i], i is the NodeID (or well the vertice ID | Vx[i]).
How can I do that?

---

EDIT:
I tried to do:

```
for(PathType::reverse_iterator pathIterator = path.rbegin(); pathIterator !=       path.rend(); ++pathIterator) 
{ 
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_NODES; ++i)
    {
        if(source(*pathIterator, dgraph) == *((Vertex*)Vx[i]))
        {
            cout  << "  " << i << "  " << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

but this just crashes..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `typedef`s from that question, you can use `get(boost::vertex_index, dgraph, v)` to get the index of `v`.  You can also cache the property map using:

```
IndexMap vi = get(boost::vertex_index, dgraph);
```

then use `get(vi, v)` to get the index for `v`.

Comment: Thank you, Finally I did get(vi, source(*pathIterator, dgraph)) and that works great!